# python pandas csv file conversion of integers to binary

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file like that

```
Meme1, Meme2, Meme3, Meme4, Meme5, Meme6
Meme1, Meme2, Meme3, Meme99, Meme5, Meme6
Meme5, Meme2, Meme2, Meme4, Meme10, Meme6
Meme99, Meme3, Meme4, Meme4, Meme5, Meme6
```

I want like that

```
00000001, 00000010, 00000011, 00000100, 00000101, 00000110
00000001, 00000010, 01100011, 00000100, 00000101, 00000110
00000100, 00000010, 00000010, 00000100, 00001010, 00000110
```

means every integer should be converted to binary and word meme should be deleted

```
I am trying but cannot do:(
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy as np

dataset = pd.read_csv('datsetcoma.txt')
reader = csv.DictReader(dataset)
print (reader)
 # print back the headers
for row in reader:
    if row.is_integer:
      
       b=np.binary_repr(10, width=8)
       print (b)
```

Comment: Do you have only Meme or there are other words?

Comment: only meme @Phoenix

Comment: So what if there are strings like `foo123bar456`?

Comment: only meme with different integers @ifly6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

# example taken from @ifly6  
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''Meme1, Meme2, Meme3, Meme4, Meme5, Meme6
Meme1, Meme2, Meme3, Meme99, Meme5, Meme6
Meme5, Meme2, Meme2, Meme4, Meme10, Meme6
Meme99, Meme3, Meme4, Meme4, Meme5, Meme6'''), header=None)

df.apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda y:  bin(int(y.replace('Meme', '')))[2:].zfill(8) ) ) 

#output

          0         1         2         3         4         5
0  00000001  00000010  00000011  00000100  00000101  00000110
1  00000001  00000010  00000011  01100011  00000101  00000110
2  00000101  00000010  00000010  00000100  00001010  00000110
3  01100011  00000011  00000100  00000100  00000101  00000110
```

Comment: facing this error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: I updated the answer, try to run the entire solution at once.

Comment: yeah, its working THANKS but how can I give full CSV FILE with pandas io LIKE df = pd.read_csv(io.my-file.csv) rather then stringio?

Answer (score 1):

Loading the DF using `import io` with no headers, I extract the integers using a regular expression without expansion. Then cast to integer types. Because `np.binary_repr` is not vectorised, I have to "vectorise" it.

Because `np` methods do not retain indexing, I then reproduce the indicies (which is needed to retain row and column positions that are preserved in the multi-index) in the `pd.Series` constructor and unstack back to the original data frame shape.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''Meme1, Meme2, Meme3, Meme4, Meme5, Meme6
Meme1, Meme2, Meme3, Meme99, Meme5, Meme6
Meme5, Meme2, Meme2, Meme4, Meme10, Meme6
Meme99, Meme3, Meme4, Meme4, Meme5, Meme6'''), header=None)

s = df.stack()
s = s.str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
pd.Series(np.vectorize(np.binary_repr)(s, width=8), index=s.index).unstack()
```

The final output,

```
          0         1         2         3         4         5
0  00000001  00000010  00000011  00000100  00000101  00000110
1  00000001  00000010  00000011  01100011  00000101  00000110
2  00000101  00000010  00000010  00000100  00001010  00000110
3  01100011  00000011  00000100  00000100  00000101  00000110
```

Nb your binary conversions in the original post are not all accurate. Eg `Meme5` is erroneously converted to `00000100` when it should be `00000101`. The OP version also omits (probably for convenience) the final row.

Nb also that this will not work if there are multiple expansion groups. In a comment I posited the hypothetical example `foo123bar456`. This would result in two expansion groups which would disturb the indexing.

Comment: yeah, its working THANKS but how can I give full CSV FILE with pandas io LIKE df = pd.read_csv(io.my-file.csv) rather then stringio?

Comment: I mean you are giving string i wanna give full file

Comment: Just load the file directly like normal... https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html